# Mongo median operation in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregate

I have collection in mongo (go) which type is:

```
type CreateFeedbackRequest struct {
    UserID     string    `json:"user_id" validate:"required"`
    WaybillID  uint64    `json:"waybill_id" validate:"required"`
    Rating     int       `json:"rating" validate:"required"`
    Comment    string    `json:"comment"`
    ReceivedAt time.Time `json:"received_at" validate:"required"`
}
```

I need to evaluate median value of rating for last 5 records (by `receivedAt` time field) for certain user (by his `user_id`).
I have already got this:

```
matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"_id", userID}}}}
sortStage := bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{{"created_at", 1}}}}
limitStage := bson.D{{"$limit", tripsCount}}

cursor, err := r.c.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, sortStage, limitStage})
```

But I don't know then how to got rating median for this 5 rows. And I am not sure about correct way I'm doing this. Help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `$limit` stage, one option since mongodb version 7.0 is to `$group` with `$median` accumulator

```
groupgStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{
  {"_id", 0}, 
  {"median", bson.D{{"$median", 
    bson.D{{"$input", "$rating"}, {"method", "approximate"}}
  }}}
}}}
```

For older versions, you can

1. `$sort` by `rating`
2. `$group` and `$push` all `rating`s to an array (all 5 of them after you limit)
3. `$project` the item in the middle of the array

It will look like that:

```
sortRatingStage := bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{{"rating", 1}}}}
groupStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", 0}, {"ratings", bson.D{{"$push", "ratings"}}}}}}
projectStage := bson.D{{"$project", bson.D{
  {"_id", 0}, 
  {median, bson.D{{"$arrayElemAt", bson.D{
    {"$ratings", bson.D{{"$floor", bson.D{
      {"$divide", bson.A{{bson.D{{"$size", "$ratings"}}, 2}}}
    }}}}
  }}}}
}}}}
```

Comment: could you please check your code for new mongo version? it displays an error

Comment: I can't check it, as I don;t have mongoDB version 7.0. This is the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/median/). What is the error? What is your mongoDB version?

Comment: too many values for line "bson.D{{"method", "approximate"}}". if i delete it - its ok. mongo driver 1.12.1

Comment: Updated according to your remark. Thanks!